# Revert a whole directory in tortoise svn?

Tags: svn, version-control

For one reason or another I had to empty folder in my subversion repository and replace its contents! I done this using tortoise svn.

Can I get the files I removed from the repository back?

I have tried doing it throught the log but it appears to only let you revert back files, I need the whole contents of a directory!

Thanks

UPDATE:

There was a problem with tortoise, I managed to checkout a previous version from the log, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the easiest option would be to do a new checkout to a separate location, of the folder **at the version you want** (i.e. before you deleted them) - then copy the files over.

Comment: I have tried checking out the right version from the log but it doesn't seem to be working!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the easiest way is to check out an earlier version of your project. If you cannot find the right files, try checking out successively earlier version of the repository until you find the right version.

Another easier way would be to get some software that allows you to browse and manage your repositories. I find it quite easy to use "Versions" on Mac, or "Eclipse" with the "subclipse" plugin on windows.

If the tool your using, (ie tortise) is not that useful, find a better one.